# While installing eOS the system asks to login in tty1

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, install

I'm quite new to Linux and decided to install elementary OS on my PC. The problem is that I'm not sure how am I supposed to continue the installation. Currently there's just a black terminal screen saying:

```
elementary OS Next elementary tty1

elementary login:
```

Answer (score 0):

did you find a solution? I am having the same problem.

I don't think that this is supposed to happen, can you give some more details about the hardware that you are installing on (Is it a laptop or desktop, How old is it, do you know which graphics card and motherboard that you are using?)

Answer (score 0):

I heard that the default installation user is `elementary`, but that this will not be helpful as the installer doesn't seem to have more than one sudo terminal in the installer.  Also the installer doesn't seem to have a GUI, nor an init script for the xsession.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen while trying the OS out in a virtual machine. Went into my host pc's browser to search for how to log in, but by the time I looked back at the installation window there was a dialog asking for language/keyboard choices. I *think* maybe the login request times itself out if it isn't answered. I seem to be proceeding with the installation, anyway. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can happen if one of the following conditions are met:

1. there is insufficient storage space on the computer (e.g. the internal storage is not appearing to the installer)
2. there is insufficient video memory allocated (only happens with some older Intel chips with integrated video)
3. the installation media is *very* slow (e.g. when trying to install with a USB 1.1 key)
4. the video card is "too new" for the Linux kernel to handle
5. the video card is too old/weak to render the UI
6. the installation media is corrupted

The most common situation that I have seen is the last one. If possible, try to create the installation USB (or DVD) again to see if the problem persists.